# 暗号化ライブラリのpycryptoをpipでインストールするとエラーが出る。

Tags: python, python3

pythonのパッケージのpycriptoをpip installしようとすると、以下のエラーの表示がでて最後まで実行できません。

windows10  python3.6  anaconda導入済み　msVS2017インストール済み　です。

ネットで調べてはみたのですが解決しませんでした。
何かいい解決策はありませんか？よろしくお願いします。（******はユーザー名です）

```
    C:\Users\******>pip install pycrypto
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\******\desktop\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dlelcucn\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4drr4pk1\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\crosby.red\desktop\python36\include -Ic:\users\crosby.red\desktop\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: 構文エラー: 識別子 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: 構文エラー: 識別子 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: 構文エラー: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: 構文エラー: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: 構文エラー: 識別子 'imaxdiv_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: 構文エラー: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: 構文エラー: ')' が、識別子 '_Number' の前に必要です。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: 構文エラー: 識別子 '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: 構文エラー: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: 構文エラー: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: 構文エラー: ')' が、識別子 '_Numerator' の前に必要です。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: 構文エラー: 識別子 '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: 構文エラー: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: 構文エラー: ','
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: 構文エラー: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: 構文エラー: '{' が '__cdecl' の前にありません。
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\******\desktop\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dlelcucn\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4drr4pk1\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dlelcucn\pycrypto\
```

Answer (score 2):

pycryptoの開発は終了しており、[pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome)への移行を推奨されているようです。

> tl;dr: PyCrypto is dead.
>   Switch to PyCryptodome (GitHub: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodome).
>   https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/238

なお、WindowsでのビルドエラーはIssueとして上がっています。（こちらでもPycryptodomeへの移行をうながされています。）
[Windows Pycrypto Build Issues/Not Supported · Issue #25 · CiscoUcs/intersight-python](https://github.com/CiscoUcs/intersight-python/issues/25)

Comment: picoSushiさん、回答ありがとうございます！ソース拝見しました。つまりpycryptoではなくpycryptodomeをpip installすればよかったのでしょうか？やってみたところ、pip listで確認すると
Package      Version
------------ -------
colorama     0.3.9
Pillow       5.2.0
pip          18.0
pycryptodome 3.6.6
pygame       1.9.3
qrcode       6.0
setuptools   28.8.0
six          1.11.0　　　のようにでました。

Comment: はい。 `pycryptodome 3.6.6 ` と出たのなら、正常にインストール出来ているかと存じます。

Comment: わかりました。教えていただきありがとうございます！