# pycryptoを使ったデータの暗号化に失敗する

Tags: python, python3, pycrypto

あるデータとパスワードを暗号化するプログラムを、pycryptoを使用して作っていたところ、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\Python教科書\crypto-test.py", line 51, in <module>
    enc = encrypt(password, message)
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\Python教科書\crypto-test.py", line 30, in encrypt
    aes = AES.new(password, mode, iv)
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 206, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 253, in _create_cbc_cipher
    return CbcMode(cipher_state, iv)
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 96, in __init__
    c_uint8_ptr(iv),
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 196, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

これはC言語かpycryptoに関することが原因なのでしょうか。ancondaをインストール済みです。

元のプログラムはこちらです。

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64


# 暗号化したいデータとパスワードを指定

message = "自分がしてほしいと思うことをヒトのもするように。"
password = "xxxxxxxxxx"     # 適当なパスワードを設定
iv = "L3f4mlTJtCIPV9af"     # 初期化ベクトル(16文字で適当な値を設定)
mode = AES.MODE_CBC     # 暗号化モードを指定


# 特定の長さの倍数にするため空白でデータを埋める関数

def mkpad(s, size):
    s = s.encode("utf-8")       # UTF-8文字列をバイト列に変換する
    pad = b' ' * (size - len(s) % size)     # 特定の長さの倍数にするための空白を生成
    return s + pad


# 暗号化する

def encrypt(password, data):
    # 特定の長さに調節する
    password = mkpad(password, 16)      # 16の倍数にそろえる
    data = mkpad(data, 16)      # バイト列に変換し16の倍数に揃える
    password = password[:16]        # ちょうど16文字に揃える

    # 暗号化
    aes = AES.new(password, mode, iv)
    data_cipher = aes.encrypt(data)
    return base64.b64encode(data_cipher).decode("utf-8")


# 複合化する

def decrypt(password, encdata):
    # パスワードの文字数を調整
    password = mkpad(password, 16)      # 16の倍数に揃える
    password = password[:16]        # ちょうど16文字に揃える

    # 複合化
    aes = AES.new(password, mode, iv)
    encdata = base64.b64decode(encdata)     # 暗号化データをBASE64でデコードしてバイト列に
    data = aes.decrypt(encdata)     # 複合化
    return data.decode("utf-8")


# 暗号化する
enc = encrypt(password, message)

# 複合化する
dec = decrypt(password, enc)


# 結果を表示する

print("暗号化", enc)
print("複合化", dec)
```

何かいい解決策があれば教えていただきたいです。お願いします。

Comment: [前回のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48749/19110)で PyCryptodome をオススメされていたかと思いますが、こちらは PyCrypto でしょうか、PyCryptodome でしょうか？　バージョン情報と一緒に本文へ追記して頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: エラーが `_raw_api.py` で発生していることから、`PyCrypto` ではなく `PyCryptodome` の `Crypto.Cipher.AES` がインポートされているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、pycryptoのcryptoを使用するつもりでやっています。pycriptodomeから使用する方法がわからないのですが、これでないとやはりだめなのでしょうか。

Comment: ＠metropolis さん、fromをCryptoからCryptodomeに変更しても同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。単に変更すればいいということではないのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、掲載されているソースコードは、PyCrypto の API で書かれていますので、Cryptodome の API で書き直す必要があります。

Comment: @metropolis さん、というとコードは大幅に変わるということであってますか？でしたら簡単に変更点をお教えできたた学の狭い私にはありがたいです。

Comment: 初期化ベクトルも byte 型に変換する必要があります。例えば、`iv = "L3f4mlTJtCIPV9af".encode('utf-8')` とするなどです。

Comment: @metropolis さん、お手数おかけします。無事に動作いたしました。本当にありがとうございます。勉強がんばります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文に書かれているエラーログは、PyCrypto のものではなく PyCryptodome のものに見えます。PyCryptodome で動かすのであれば、そのための変更が必要です。

[質問者さんによる前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48749/19110)に書かれている通り現在 PyCrypto は非推奨であり、PyCryptodome への移行が推奨されています。どちらで書いても `import` 文は一緒になるため同じように使えそうですが、いくつか違いがあります。

API レベルの主な変更点は、PyCryptodome のドキュメント ["Compatibility with PyCrypto"](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html) に書かれています。また、[Changelog](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changelog.html) に書かれている変更点も別に注意が必要です。

更にこれ以外にも細かい変更点があるようです。たとえば metropolis さんが[コメントでご指摘なさっている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48764/pycrypto%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E6%9A%97%E5%8F%B7%E5%8C%96%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B#comment50687_48764)ように、`Crypto.Cipher.AES.new()` の引数 `iv` の受け付けるものが ["byte string"](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html) から ["bytes, bytearray, memoryview"](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html#Crypto.Cipher.AES.new) に変わっています。今回のエラーはこの違いに由来するもので、`iv` に string を渡すと質問文に書かれたエラーが出ます。bytes にすればよいので、たとえば

```
iv = "L3f4mlTJtCIPV9af".encode('utf-8')
```

とすればエラーを回避できます。